# How to filter items that are 24 hours past Created in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

We have `List1` with a workflow that moves items created to `List2` once the Status field changes to certain values. I am attempting to create a view that shows:

a) items that have remained in List1 24 hours and greater after they were created; and

b) displays the actual time that has lapsed since the item was created.

I have used Calculated Columns and tried `=INT((NOW()-Created)*24)` and made the Calculated Column a number with 0 decimals, but when the Status changes it changes the number to several decimal points and the view is no longer accurate.

I have also tried the following in a Calculated Column, but the `Now()` value only displays the date/time the Calculated Column was created not exact current date/time which I'm measuring against:

```
=DATEDIF([Created],Now()-(MOD([Created],1)>MOD(Now(),1)),"d")&" days, "&TEXT(MOD(Now()-[Created],1),"hh "" hrs, "" mm "" mins""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar scenario with [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254111/compare-two-fields-in-sharepoing-using-calculated-column), so I suggest you use CSR to override field render based on item Created.

More about SharePoint CSR.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views